# Как удалить предыдущее сообщение Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

При нажатии отправляется ссылка на статью в *telegraph*. При нажатии еще раз на кнопку (ту же или другую) нужно удалять предыдущее сообщение со ссылкой.

```py
# Отправление ссылок на аддоны
@dp.callback_query(F.data.in_(telegraphLinks))
async def send_addon1(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.answer(telegraphLinks[callback.data])
```

Забор ссылок и колбэков идет через словарь

```py
telegraphLinks: dict[str, str] = {'raid': 'https://telegra.ph/Rejdovye-addony-09-12',
        'inventoryAndBank': 'https://telegra.ph/Inventar-i-Bank-09-12'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для удаления сообщения юзайте `await callback.message.delete()`